# Prostration before bricks

Tags: greek, egyptian, worship

The Talmud in [Sanhedrin 107b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.107b.12-14?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) and [Sotah 47a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.47a.12-14?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) brings a story about a sage named Yehoshua ben Perachiah and one of his students, called Jesus (whether this Jesus is the famous one of Christianity is beside the point here). At the end of the story, the rabbi and his student have a falling out and the student decides to commit an act of idolatry: Placing a brick upright and bowing down to it. Earlier today, I saw a suggestion by Avraham Korman in his book "Sects and Cults in Judaism", pg. 364, that this act was probably something he had learned while staying in Egypt (in the story, he and his rabbi had escaped to Egypt and then came back to Judea).

Was there such a form of worship in ancient Egypt or Hellenistic Egypt (when the story took place)?

(Note: a "brick" here could be any size, not necessarily a small one, or it might even refer to a stone slab of some sort, but likely of a type used for building things)